# Changing Mouse Pointer position in FULLSCREEN

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possible to change the mouse-pointer position in fullscreen. I want my mousepointer never hits the left or right side screen walls.. in case it does so, it resets itself in between somewhere.

A fake mouse pointer using a movieclip, won't solve this problem, because after-all i have to save the mouse pointer from hitting screen-walls.

Thanks
V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it yet, but Adobe announced mouse-lock for the next version of the Flash Player. [Here's a link to the download page of Flash Player 11.2 release candidate](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplatformruntimes/flashplayer11-2/).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really set the mouse coordinates from AS3. They are [read only properties](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#mouseX).

I would suggest using the dummy mouse pointer & fooling user from hitting the walls.

Alternatively, you might need help from javascript.